# Combining 3 Tables and Finding the Count for Fruit in SQL

Tags: sql, union, hue

I need to combine three tables and find the total count for fruit after combining the three tables using SQL. The name of the fruit columns in the three tables are pr16pnk.fruit, pr16puf.fruit, and pr16yag.fruit. I have successfully found the results when the tables are separated, but I am having trouble combining the results. Listed below is the code that I used. I also need help putting it in descending order.

```
SELECT pr16pnk.fruit, COUNT(*)  
FROM pr16pnk  
GROUP BY pr16pnk.fruit 
UNION ALL
SELECT pr16puf.fruit, COUNT(*)  
FROM pr16puf  
GROUP BY pr16puf.fruit 
UNION ALL
SELECT pr16yag.fruit, COUNT(*)  
FROM pr16yag  
GROUP BY pr16yag.fruit
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a subquery:

```
SELECT fruit, SUM(cnt)
FROM ((SELECT pr16pnk.fruit, COUNT(*) as cnt 
       FROM pr16pnk  
       GROUP BY pr16pnk.fruit 
      ) UNION ALL
       SELECT pr16puf.fruit, COUNT(*) as cnt
       FROM pr16puf  
       GROUP BY pr16puf.fruit 
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT pr16yag.fruit, COUNT(*) as cnt
       FROM pr16yag  
       GROUP BY pr16yag.fruit 
      )
     ) f
GROUP BY fruit
```

Comment: @IsabellaKnightly . . . Please explain how it did not work.  Your comment is not helpful.

Comment: I keep receiving Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException 7:5 Schema of both sides of union should match. f-subquery1-subquery2 does not have the field cnt. Error encountered near token 'pr16puf'

Comment: @IsabellaKnightly . . . That is a really strange error.  The SQL engine should be taking the names from the first subquery.  But you might be able to fix it just by adding `as cnt` to the other two subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregators and ORDER BY, query is as simple as below

```
SELECT sum(A.fruit ,B.fruit, C.fruit)
 FROM pr16pnk A
      pr16puf B'
      pr16yag C
ORDER BY fruit desc;
```

Comment: I keep receiving an error message that says Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 3:0 missing EOF at 'pr16puf' near 'A'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select f.fruit, count(*) from 
(
    SELECT pr16pnk.fruit from pr16pnk
    union 
    SELECT pr16puf.fruit from pr16puf
    union
    SELECT pr16yag.fruit from pr16yag
) f
group by f.fruit
order by f.fruit desc
```